# How to use Postprocessing on an awt or swing window

Tags: java, swing, awt, post-processing

Is it possible to use Post Processing effects like gaussian blur or greyscale effects on an entire JFrame independent from its contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you are looking at the `JLayer` class. See [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for more information and examples.

Another option might be to use a `Glass Pane`. See the `glass pane demo` from [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).